# Would an "all-servers" tag be appropriate/welcome?

Tags: discussion

I'm planning on asking a question.

Now, while I plan to put PostgreSQL as the "major" server for the question, there is no reason (and I am interested) that replies for other servers couldn't be either helpful, interesting, useful... or all of the above.

So, I'm just wondering if there'd be any demand at all for having an `all-servers` tag for questions which fall into this category?

Answer (score 4):

No, because no one will ever look for `all-servers` tag.

Just drop it entirely. It's assumed if you don't specify a specific RDBMS that it's applicable to all of them. But that's really not useful, so it seems likely you'll be *forced* to specify, and I'm cool with that.

Basically you're either asking about

- A specific RDBMS product
- The SQL Spec.

I can't see a question applying to every RDBMS product being useful.

Comment: The `all-servers` tag would just as a hint that it's **not just** the "major server". I would be interested in alternative approaches taken by other RDBMS - to see if there are features there that I might be interested in - I know it's kinda vague/non-specifice, but I don't think that it's necessarily possible to nail every question down to one particular server and that one only. I'm hoping my question will provoke some open-ended debate about the topic (which IMHO is of interest to the group), while at the same time remaining strictly technical.

Comment: Anyway, it's just a thought on my part - I can always express these sentiments at the beginning of the question anyway - thanks for your input!